# Download a file to Downloads folder of device using Cordova FileTransfer

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova FileTransfer object to download a file from a url to device.

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var path = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
 fileTransfer.download(
        fileUrl,
        path + "/sample.pdf",
        function(theFile) {
            console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
            alert("File downloaded to "+cordova.file.dataDirectory);
        },
        function(error) {              
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
```

In this case the file is downloaded to `data/data/com.fileDemo/files/`
(I am not sure whether download is success as I can't access this folder. Getting success message as `download complete: file:///data/data/com.fileDemo/files/sample.pdf`).
How can I use the same method to download a file to "Downloads" folder of the android device?

Answer (score 5):

In Cordova, with  `FileTransfer`, you can request `TEMPORARY` or `PERSISTENT` file system

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

> - iOS
>
>   - `PERSISTENT` will return the Documents directory,
>   - `TEMPORARY` will return the Caches directory
> - Android
>
>   - `PERSISTENT` will returns the root of the SD card/phone memory
>   - `TEMPORARY` will return a folder inside the data folder.

Refer [`File API`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) & [`FileTransfer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) for more info.

Comment: I just tried this, but the gotFs points to the application's data folder. not the Download folder right under the root. Is that possible to access the Download folder that under the root directory?

Comment: For those who still stuck this issue, either `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/'` or `fileSystem.root.toURL() + 'Download/'`should work